# How to only get email notifications for one Yahoo account Samsung Galaxy 7 Sprint?

Tags: notifications

I only want to get email notifications on home screen (Samsung Galaxy 7 Sprint phone) for one of my yahoo email accounts. HOW can I change this?

Comment: Are you using Samsung's built-in e-mail client, or Yahoo's own [Yahoo Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) app?

Comment: I just set-up phone last week, and I think I am using both. (Maybe that's the problem?). I downloaded Yahoo app and Yahoo icon on home page is how I get to inbox. (BTW, I also still can't figure out how to sign-out of inbox it opens to get to my other yahoo email accounts).

Comment: Continued...Galaxy 7 home page is notifying me of incoming messages from all 3 yahoo email accounts I have, but I only want to receive notifications from one...And I need to know how/where I go to be able to get to all 3 accounts to quickly check messages.  I can't find anywhere to log out and sign in to other yahoo email..I get into it through both Yahoo icon on home screen and through Yahoo app icon. (BTW, So far I hate this sprint galaxy 7 phone--hardest phone I've ever had to customize/set-up.